# How to make this code vertical-align to the bottom

Tags: html

Got this simple piece of html code and I want to make the TEST (third `<td>` component) align to the bottom of the row but it stays up no matter what I try.

I know there are thousands of questions of this sort and I read 3-4 articles but non of the stuff I tried works.

```
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="144" height="125"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="CommuniTake" width="143"
                height="123"></td>
            <td width="775">
            <h1><h:outputText value="#{msg.General_Configuration_Title}" /></h1>
            </td>
            <td style="float:right;vertical-align:text-bottom">
            TEST
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried vertical-align:bottom?

Comment: It is shameful to use tables for layout. Use DIVs instead.

Comment: You should aim to keep the code for your styles out of the markup for proper Separation of Concerns.

Comment: Tnx Both, I know it's a very bad idea but it's what I got and I might change that as well once I resolve this issue...

Comment: Ben, you comment that things are depreciated, yet you are using tables for layouts which sort of depreciated a long time ago. "I might change that as well once..." Change Now!

Comment: @Tim - it's "deprecated"

Comment: I'm already on it.. Trying to get the `divs` and `spans` look like the table design..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `float` and make it `vertical-align: bottom` and it'll fall to the abyss!

Comment: Tnx. That Works. But I need it to float to the right. What Can I do?

Answer (score 2):

```
<td valign="bottom">
```

should work

Comment: at the first glance you should not use tables for design layout

Comment: Yeah :-) That's also correct. Anyway.. I tried it and it didn't work. I'm trying to see how to combine float and vertical-align since it seems that `float` is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="144" height="125"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="CommuniTake" width="143"
            height="123"></td>
        <td width="775">
        <h1><h:outputText value="#{msg.General_Configuration_Title}" /></h1>
        </td>
        <td valign="bottom">
        TEST
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've rad that valign should not be used... (Deprecated)

Comment: @Ben: So is the table :) I just tried the above code and it aligns to the bottom as you describe.

Answer (score 0):

From [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp):

> text-bottom   The bottom of the element is aligned with the bottom of the parent element's font

Might be that this td does not have a parent element, which has font to align to. Using simple '*bottom*', as suggested by others, would align to lowest element on the same line.